# What denominations obligate daily Bible reading and prayer?

Tags: prayer, religious-practice

It is my understanding that the default position within mainstream Christianity is that prayer and reading the Bible are key to promoting spiritual well-being and growth and that as such they are extremely important for growing in faith and maintaining it. However, I was wondering if any denominations obligate (by which I mean set as the rule for life in a similar fashion to prayer in mainstream Islam) daily prayer and Bible reading? Conversely are there any actively discourage daily prayer and/or daily Bible reading?

Comment: I should clarify that you are talking denominations - e.g. Baptist or Episcopalian, as opposed to say, orders of cloistered folk, such as Benedictines or Jesuits.  Logistically, "enforcing" any sort of mandate in a setting beyond a single cloister is considerably more difficult.

Comment: That is indeed the case. By mandate I mean counsel as a rule for life like prayer in mainstream Islam.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "mandate"?  Certainly some types of Pentecostals will "tut-tut" you if you don't do these things, JWs may "censure" you - but I doubt any of them will excommunicate you or kick you out.

Comment: @Affablegeek - what do you think about my above suggestion?

Comment: I guess that works.  Again, enforcement is going to be the issue - and it all misses grace anyway.

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User It is a highly recommended, good thing and beneficial thing to do. Waiting for the answers to see who teaches "you must" ...

Comment: With your last question "Conversely are there any actively discourage it?", do you mean any that discourage *mandating* prayer and bible study or any that discourage prayer and bible study themselves?

Comment: Well I meant discourage daily prayer and Bible reading. I was imagining something perhaps from the emergent church or somesuch. Perhaps one of the more mystical strains of the orthodox faith? This is all just guess work. I've edited this question accordingly.

Comment: By mandate, do you mean people are taught to do it, and so get a bad conscience when they don't, or what do you mean? Is it enough to teach it is a commandment, or what are you looking for?

Comment: @kutschkem What do you find insufficient about the way mandate is defined in the question?

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User You assume everyone is familiar with Islamic practices. Are Muslims chastised if they forget or neglect to pray for a day? Could you specify when you say, "mandate", do you mean to imply that there would be secular repercussions by the leadership of the church? Or that it's a general rule that the members are admonished to follow.

Comment: @ShemSeger It is considered obligatory (with a few exceptions for young children, menstruating women etc.) but there is not regimented enforcement - that is not realistically possible outside a monastic setting. Sorry, I'm very used to being around a substantial Muslim population. To be fair I get rather lost when people draw comparisons to the LDS or Jehovah's witnesses and the like as I've had minimal contact with them.

Comment: I suppose we all live in our own bubble.

Comment: Mandate implies mandatory. Surely - as one who identifies with Anglicanism - you are aware of [canonical hours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_hours) or the daily office? I can think of no Christian denomination that _makes_ one pray.

Comment: I am indeed familiar with the canonical hours. I think a very small edit might improve this question. Mandate might be too strong a term with obligate being much better. Obligate says that you should be doing this but doesn't carry the same connotation of someone standing over you making absolutely sure you do it.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am unsure whether this answer fits your intended meaning of "mandatory" or "obligatory".

LDS members are taught they should have daily scripture study and prayer. In fact, in the handbook for missionaries, "Preach my gospel", scripture study and prayer are listed in the chapter about commandments, to be taught to potential converts before their baptism [citation needed]. This normally means they will also invite people to commit themselves to have regular scripture study and prayer.

Our leaders, who we believe to be apostles of the same authority as the ancient ones, frequently tell us the same thing. This goes so far to specifically say we should make a habit of praying in the morning when we get up and in the evening before we go to bed [citation needed].

In D&C 20:47, when talking about the duties of a priest, the priesthood holders are explicitely told to make sure the families pray both openly (family prayer) and in secret (personal prayer).

So, we definitely think of regular prayer and scripture study as divine commandments.

Of course the reason why we need to be told these things so often is that many struggle throughout their lives to make such habits. There are no measures the church takes against people who neglect these things. A big part of the personal spiritual life, however, certainly lives off these things.

Comment: This is a good start and it is indeed the kind of thing I was looking for.